# Gulp file ordering not as expected

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

I have the glob:

```
'app/scripts/page-*/js/*.js'
```

How can I get gulp to sort the following 2 files in this order:

```
page-user.js
page-user-create.js
```

I need page-xxx.js to always go first. I tried `gulp-natural-sort` using both ascending and descending order but I still get the same result:

```
page-user-create.js
page-user.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`gulp-order`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-order) instead:

```
.pipe(order([
  'page-*([^-]).js',
  'page-*-*.js'
]))
```

This should sort all files with a single `-` in their file name before those files with two `-` in their file name.

Comment: I guess this could work but I didnt use or like this solution because it requires to maintain a separate ordering config (cant feed this into gulp.src()) and it messed up the order of my other files. So I cant really use this solution standalone to fix my issue, I'd need to define a full config for ordering the rest of my files correctly. It just seems like a path I didnt want to   go down. Instead, I just appended '-main' to the files I wanted first and used 2 globs like `['page-*-main.js', 'page-*.js']`. KISS. Thanks though